# How to select all images in the page?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, resolution, retina-display

I have this jQuery-script that gives any image or object with tag `data-retina="true"` a `retina-resolution-image` or `background-image`.

But how do I remove the last part from the script so that this function will apply on every image, not just the one with the `data-retina` tag?

```
 (function($) {
    "use strict";

    var retinaReplace = function(element, options) {

        this.options = options;
        var $el = $(element);
        var is_image = $el.is('img');
        var normal_url = is_image ? $el.attr('src') : $el.backgroundImageUrl();
        var retina_url = this.options.generateUrl($el, normal_url);

        $('<img/>').attr('src', retina_url).load(function() {

            if (is_image) {
                $el.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            } else {
                $el.backgroundImageUrl($(this).attr('src'));
                $el.backgroundSize($(this)[0].width, $(this)[0].height);
            }

            $el.attr('data-retina', 'complete');
        });
    }

    retinaReplace.prototype = {
        constructor: retinaReplace
    }

    $.fn.retinaReplace = function(option) {

        if (getDevicePixelRatio() <= 1) { return this; }

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var data = $this.data('retinaReplace');
            var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.retinaReplace.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option);
            if (!data) { $this.data('retinaReplace', (data = new retinaReplace(this, options))); }
            if (typeof option == 'string') { data[option](); }
        });
    }

    $.fn.retinaReplace.defaults = {
        suffix: '-x2', 
        generateUrl: function(element, url) {
            var dot_index = url.lastIndexOf('.');
            var extension = url.substr(dot_index + 1);
            var file = url.substr(0, dot_index);
            return file + this.suffix + '.' + extension;
        }
    }

    $.fn.retinaReplace.Constructor = retinaReplace;

    var getDevicePixelRatio = function() {
        if (window.devicePixelRatio === undefined) { return 1; }
        return window.devicePixelRatio;
    }

    $.fn.backgroundImageUrl = function(url) {
        return url ? this.each(function () { 
            $(this).css("background-image", 'url("' + url + '")')
        }) : $(this).css("background-image").replace(/url\(|\)|"|'/g, "");
    }

    $.fn.backgroundSize = function(retinaWidth, retinaHeight) {
        var sizeValue = Math.floor(retinaWidth/2) + 'px ' + Math.floor(retinaHeight/2) + 'px';
        $(this).css("background-size", sizeValue);
        $(this).css("-webkit-background-size", sizeValue);
    }

    $(function(){
        $("[data-retina='true']").retinaReplace();
    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: I got the feeling, you didn't write all that code...

Answer (score 2):

> how do I remove the last part from the script so that this function will apply on every image, not just the once with the data-retina-tag?

**Change:**

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-retina='true']").retinaReplace();
});
```

**To:**

```
$(function(){
    $("img").retinaReplace();
});
```

Comment: Will that also apply for the objects with a background-image CSS, or just pure images ( <img src=""> )?

Comment: $("img") selects all image elements. This does not include css background-image elements.

Comment: @user1484703. Define _"objects with a background-image"_. How do the look like?

Comment: well, I would say that it is every html-object that could have a css background-image. Because this is a script you can add to any page to get a retina resolution IF there are high res images.

Comment: @user1484703. **Could** have? You could have a css background for almost every element. Did you mean **have** css background?

Comment: No, all that could have. This script checks all objects that has the data-retina="true" and gives their img or background-img source a -x2.jpg at the end if there is a -x2.jpg image available. The change I would like to make is for this to function on all objects, not just the once that are taged.. how do I change the script?

Comment: The script, as mentioned, just changes the object that, as you say, has an image background or is an image, so it doesn´t make changes unless it´s possible.

Comment: Here you can see the code on http://jsfiddle.net/Bua4U/

Here you can see a working example: 

http://www.7an.se/TEST/120625retina-script 

The thing is that you´ll need a iPhone 4, iPad 3 or the Retina Macbook Pro 15" to see the results..